# Send firebase cloud message aka push notification to multiple, more then 3 topics, at a time

Tags: push-notification, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to find a way to send messages to multiple topics using firebase cloud messages. 
I see [in the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/topic-messaging#sending_topic_messages_from_the_server) that there is a way to send to a field `condition` instead of field `to` and I can write a condition

`'TopicA' in topics || 'TopicB' in topics || 'TopicC' in topics`

but there is a constraint

> Conditions for topics support two operators per expression

Which means I can only send a message up to three topics at once. 
Is there a way to send a message to more then 3 topics at a time?

Comment: Same problem here... Seems firebase is to new atm, but can't realize they released notification feature with so many functionality lacks... :(

Answer (score 2):

The limit is 3 topics, you can send to more via multiple send requests, e.g. send to "a || b || c", then to "d || e || f".

By doing this some users might receive the same message twice, e.g. if they're in both topic "a" and "d", so you would need to handle this in your app.

Comment: Thanks, I understand what you say. Currently it looks like the way to go. But It is not the api I am looking for.

Comment: Is this solution applicable for iOS' APNS push, too? AFAIK it is not possible to handle an incoming message before revealing. Unfortunately the FCM API removed the possibility to send a message to multiple tokens (https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages#Message). Only a single token, device groups and 3 topics could be targeted. So it is impossible to migrate a more complex push logic from GCM to FCM!! :(((((